# Gulp loop config files and merge task... slow

Tags: json, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to automated my js task with gulp and a config.json file so i don't need to open gulpfile.js but only the config one. 
My code look good and is working... but Gulp complete the task in 10sec! I'm searching a way to get the task faster.

In the config file, i want to set different javascript with there own concat stuff.

Here a sample part of my config.json:

```
"javascript": {
    "watchdir": "./assets/js/src",
    "files": [{
        "basename": "script",
        "src" : ["./assets/js/src/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "./assets/js/src/TweenMax.min.js", "./assets/js/src/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js", "./assets/js/src/isotope.pkgd.min.js", "./assets/js/src/base.js"],
        "dest": "./assets/js"
    },
    {
        "basename": "contact",
        "src" : ["./assets/js/src/googlemap.js", "./assets/js/src/contact-form.js"],
        "dest": "./assets/js"
    }]
},
```

And, here my gulp task:

```
/* Scripts task */
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tasks = config.paths.javascript.files.map(function(entry){
        return gulp.src(entry.src)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(concat(entry.basename + '.js'))
        .pipe(rename({basename: entry.basename, suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(entry.dest))
    });

    return es.merge.apply(null, tasks).pipe(notify('Javascript Compiled and Minified'));
});
```

And the watch:

```
// Watch files
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'scripts'], function () {
    gulp.watch([config.paths.less.src + '/*.less'], ['less'])
    gulp.watch([config.paths.javascript.watchdir + '/*.js'], ['scripts'])
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Uglify on already uglfied libraries is a huge performance killer. Try to exclude those from your minification process, this should speed up things a lot!

+1 for using stream arrays!!

Comment: Look like if a replace uglified js with non-uglified, it's still not enough fast for a common watch task... well, it's a little bit faster but not enough for my need. I think to create a unique task for my vendor script like jquery and specifics tasks for my common js like home.js.. contact.js.. etc. That way, i will have one long task with file i don't edit.

May be it's only the mix of all the large javascript making task slow.. jQuery, Tweenmax, imagesloaded, isotope, lightgallery.